# How can I fill the height of JScrollPane with empty JTable Rows?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am putting a JTable in a JScrollPane, but the table only contain several rows, which makes the rest of the space in the pane just empty.

Is there any way I can do to make the JTable fill the entire pane? say, put empty rows so that the pane will be filled.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
table.setFillsViewportHeight( true );
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, this will just fill the viewport with the table background color, not with empty rows - Guess it depends on what is required. Personally, I think I prefer the look of this.

Comment: Yes, thats the idea. It doesn't make sense (to me) to add extra rows because then your model is not accurate since it contains filler rows which don't contain any data.

Answer (score 3):

The `JTable` method [`setPreferredScrollableViewportSize()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setPreferredScrollableViewportSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29) is another way to manage screen real estate. There's an [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553448/jtable-sorting-specific-field/4553842#4553842).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but it should work fine:

```
int rows = jTable1.getRowCount();
    int rowHeight = jTable1.getRowHeight();
    int tableHeight = jTable1.getTableHeader().getHeight()+(rows*rowHeight);
    System.out.println("JScrollpane: "+jScrollPane1.getViewport().getHeight());
    while( tableHeight<jScrollPane1.getViewport().getHeight()){
        System.out.println("JTable: "+tableHeight);
        ((DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel()).addRow(new Object[]{null,null,null,null});
        tableHeight+=rowHeight;
    }
```

Obviously, you'll need to change the model and the inserted data to whatever you're using.