# Troubles with setAutoCreateSorter(true)

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable, tablemodel

i made a jtable , and everthing is working fine so fare , but still i got a problem in sorting the values of the table .
some of my code:

```
    int nalt = (int) (1 + ((altmax - altmin) / incr));
    tabela = new JTable(new Object[nalt][6], colunas);
    for (int i = 0; i <= (nalt - 1); i = i) {
        for (double j = altmin; j <= altmax; j = j + incr) {
            Double tati = new Double(j);
            tabela.setValueAt(tati, i, 0);
            i = i + 1;
        }
    }
    tabela.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(tabela.getPreferredSize());
    tabela.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    tabela.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
    JScrollPane jps = new JScrollPane(tabela);
    panel2.add(jps);
```

the problem is , when i try to sort the columns from the higher to smaller number  i'm getting something like this :

```
950
9000 
850
80000
7500
7
6000
```

if you could help me i would appreciate it

thanks

Answer (score 2):

The sort order shown appears to be based on `String`. As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4553842/230513), your (unseen) `TableModel` must return a suitable `Comparable` type for numeric sorting, e.g. `Double.class`. See the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for examples.

Addendum: *What am I doing wrong?*

A minimal implementation of `getColumnClass()` for Double.class is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10067560/230513). Enable the automatic `RowSorter` and experiment to see the effect.

```
table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
```

Comment: oh i see , but how i do that? i tried different ways , but i can't do that. I saw alot of examples , but they are a little different of my case , because i add the values to the table by table.setValueAt(,,,), and most of the cases that i saw they add the values by creating a array , and by editing their DefaultTableModel. Sorry for my ignorance , but i'm new here , just trying to learn .

Comment: Return `Double.class` for that column in your implementation of `getColumnClass()`.

Comment: i did this : public Class<Double> table1(){
    tabela.getColumnClass(0);                               return Double.class;
 }  
                                                                and this after setting the values of the table:    table1();
  tabela.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);                    What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: A typical implementation of `getColumnClass()` for `Double.class` is shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10067560/230513). If this isn't helpful, please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows your current approach. It's hard to read code in a comment.