# comparing 2 columns in JTable for dates

Tags: java, swing, date, jtable, comparison

I want to compare the dates in 2 columns of the same table.

I currently have the following code which prints the data from column 2 and 3 of the `JTable` but what I need to do is determine if a date falls between the 2 dates of the columns. How would I do this?

```
public Object[][] betweendates (JTable table) {
    String tab ="\t";
    String newLine ="\n";
    TableModel dtm = table.getModel();
    int nRow = dtm.getRowCount(), nCol = dtm.getColumnCount();
    Object[][] tableData = new Object[nRow][nCol];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < nRow ; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 2 ; j <= 3 ; j++)
        {
            tableData[i][j] = dtm.getValueAt(i,j);
            System.out.print(tableData[i][j]);
            comparedates(tableData[i][j]);
            System.out.print("\t");
        }
        System.out.println();//create a new line
    }
    return tableData;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4553842/230513), ensure that your `TableModel` contains instances of [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html). Because `Date` is [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), you can use `compareTo()` to determine if a date, `d`, falls between two dates, where `d1` precedes or coincides with `d2`.

```
Date d1 = (Date) tableData[i][2];
Date d2 = (Date) tableData[i][3];
boolean b = (d1.compareTo(d) < 1) && (d.compareTo(d2) < 1)
```

Comment: I will give this a go

Comment: Also consider `RowFilter`, seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17854854/230513).